# Haven’t purified sperm for a year

Tags: sunni

I changed bedsheets on my bed over a year so a very lot of times but the sperm is on the actual bed and I haven’t purified it and it’s been a year so it’s probably disappeared or dried up but I always put a bedsheet above it it’s been a year and it’s probably disappeared and dried up so what do I do ? Is there any point of purifying it noe because I don’t know what bit it’s on the bed and It’s probably dried up and forever gone I don’t know what to do

Comment: Please stop asking the same question again and again this simply is a duplicate of your [former question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/67522/haven-t-purified-sperm-on-bed-for-a-year). And use related tags.

Answer (score -4):

sperm is not najs. pee is. poop is. but not sperm. you can scribble it away with nails.

Comment: Please elaborate and support your claims by evidences. And check [answer].